# Normal distribution in JS

Tags: javascript, algorithm, normal-distribution

I have this algorithm that I have to implement:

1. Generate u ~ U(0,1) - a random number between 0 and 1
2. Generate Y = Math.log(u)
3. if u <= (-(y ** 2) / 2 + y - 0.5) then go to 4, otherwise go to 1.
4. x1 = y
5. Generate u ~ U(0,1)
6. if u <= 0.5 then s = 1, else s = -1
7. x = s*x1

and the program should return x

This is the code I have written so far, but it just runs on an infinite loop and it returns nothing. How can I fix this?

```
let u = Math.random();
let y = -Math.log(u);
let e = 2.718281828459045;
let s;
let flag = false;

if (u <= e ** (-(y ** 2) / 2 + y - 0.5)) {
  flag = true;
  while (flag) {
    u = Math.random();
    y = -Math.log(u);
  }
} else {
  let x1 = y;
  u = Math.random();
  if (u <= 0.5) {
    s = 1;
  } else {
    s = -1;
  }
  x = s * x1;
  console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem.** "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_

Comment: I did not check all your code, but with `while (flag) {...}` it's a  nice active infinite loop you are creating.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to understand what's happening, you should try "divide and conquer" approach:

first, add logging to your `if` and `else` blocks to see which one is executed;

second, log something in different bits of your code: if you put

```
  console.log(`about to start while`)
  flag = true;
  while (flag) {
    console.log(`inside while`)
    u = Math.random();
    y = -Math.log(u);
  }
```

you'll see that your loop is actually infinite: you set `flag` to `true` and don't change it inside the loop, so it goes on and on.

Next, you should review your algorithm: do you need a loop? Why? When should it end? What should be done inside the loop? See, you describe that from 3 the algorithm can go to 1, so 1 should be inside the loop (otherwise it won't get repeated). In fact, you should understand how to implement 1-3, then you'll do 4-7 easily (well, you've done those already). I won't show you the whole solution so that you can learn something by yourself, but feel free to ask if you didn't get it.

Here are some bits to write better code, though:

- use `const e = 2.718281828459045`, not `let`, it is not supposed to be changed :) In fact, most of your variables should be `const` in this calculation
- don't use names like `x1`, `s` etc: it's totally unclear what they are supposed to hold (or what's the difference between `x` and `x1`). Well, it's up to you, but even you probably won't understand your own code after a month. May be if you add comments to your code showing some formula with those `x`, `s` etc, it'll be more clear
- `const s = u <= 0.5 ? 1 : -1` is shorter than using `if` and totally clear. Moreover, I'd write `const s = Math.random() <= 0.5 ? 1 : -1` instead of using an intermediate variable named in an unclear way